# Convert json to csv and taking just some key value

Tags: python

I have a problem with conversion from json to csv file. I have this data:

```
x = ''' [
{u'Plot': u'Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.', u'Rated': u'R', u'Title': u'The Shawshank Redemption', u'Ratings': [{u'Source': u'Internet Movie Database', u'Value': u'9.3/10'}, {u'Source': u'Rotten Tomatoes', u'Value': u'91%'}, {u'Source': u'Metacritic', u'Value': u'80/100'}], u'DVD': u'N/A', u'Writer': u'Stephen King (short story "Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption"), Frank Darabont (screenplay)', u'Production': u'Columbia Pictures', u'Actors': u'Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler', u'Type': u'movie', u'imdbVotes': u'1,814,175', u'Website': u'N/A', u'Director': u'Frank Darabont', u'Released': u'14 Oct 1994', u'Awards': u'Nominated for 7 Oscars. Another 19 wins & 30 nominations.', u'Genre': u'Crime, Drama', u'imdbRating': u'9.3', u'Language': u'English', u'Country': u'USA', u'BoxOffice': u'N/A', u'Runtime': u'142 min', u'imdbID': u'tt0111161', u'Metascore': u'80', u'Response': u'True', u'Year': u'1994'}
{u'Plot': u'The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.', u'Rated': u'R', u'Title': u'The Godfather', u'Ratings': [{u'Source': u'Internet Movie Database', u'Value': u'9.2/10'}, {u'Source': u'Rotten Tomatoes', u'Value': u'99%'}, {u'Source': u'Metacritic', u'Value': u'100/100'}], u'DVD': u'09 Oct 2001', u'Writer': u'Mario Puzo (screenplay), Francis Ford Coppola (screenplay), Mario Puzo (novel)', u'Production': u'Paramount Pictures', u'Actors': u'Marlon Brando, Al Pacino, James Caan, Richard S. Castellano', u'Type': u'movie', u'imdbVotes': u'1,235,597', u'Website': u'http://www.thegodfather.com', u'Director': u'Francis Ford Coppola', u'Released': u'24 Mar 1972', u'Awards': u'Won 3 Oscars. Another 23 wins & 27 nominations.', u'Genre': u'Crime, Drama', u'imdbRating': u'9.2', u'Language': u'English, Italian, Latin', u'Country': u'USA', u'BoxOffice': u'N/A', u'Runtime': u'175 min', u'imdbID': u'tt0068646', u'Metascore': u'100', u'Response': u'True', u'Year': u'1972'}
]'''
```

and I am trying to convert this to csv to be able to take just title and year from all details. When I am trying to do: `json.loads(x)`, error appears: `"ValueError: Expecting property name: line 2 column 2 (char 3)"` and I have no idea how to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: why you are adding `u` inside tripple quote ? 
remove that or pass the data using csv module directly to json module instead of raw string

Comment: I feel like the problem is due to the `u` prefix being valid python syntax, but not valid json syntax

Comment: the things is that it was generate from the loop, which i made to get this details, automatically and i dont really know how to get rid of that. Here is a loop which i used : for i in ids:
    url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i={}'.format(i)+apikey
    r = requests.get(url)
    val = json.loads(r.text)
    print val

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't in valid JSON format. It's *almost* valid Python, however. Here's how to leverage that fact and do what you want:

```
import ast
import csv

x = ''' [
{u'Plot': u'Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.', u'Rated': u'R', u'Title': u'The Shawshank Redemption', u'Ratings': [{u'Source': u'Internet Movie Database', u'Value': u'9.3/10'}, {u'Source': u'Rotten Tomatoes', u'Value': u'91%'}, {u'Source': u'Metacritic', u'Value': u'80/100'}], u'DVD': u'N/A', u'Writer': u'Stephen King (short story "Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption"), Frank Darabont (screenplay)', u'Production': u'Columbia Pictures', u'Actors': u'Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler', u'Type': u'movie', u'imdbVotes': u'1,814,175', u'Website': u'N/A', u'Director': u'Frank Darabont', u'Released': u'14 Oct 1994', u'Awards': u'Nominated for 7 Oscars. Another 19 wins & 30 nominations.', u'Genre': u'Crime, Drama', u'imdbRating': u'9.3', u'Language': u'English', u'Country': u'USA', u'BoxOffice': u'N/A', u'Runtime': u'142 min', u'imdbID': u'tt0111161', u'Metascore': u'80', u'Response': u'True', u'Year': u'1994'}
{u'Plot': u'The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.', u'Rated': u'R', u'Title': u'The Godfather', u'Ratings': [{u'Source': u'Internet Movie Database', u'Value': u'9.2/10'}, {u'Source': u'Rotten Tomatoes', u'Value': u'99%'}, {u'Source': u'Metacritic', u'Value': u'100/100'}], u'DVD': u'09 Oct 2001', u'Writer': u'Mario Puzo (screenplay), Francis Ford Coppola (screenplay), Mario Puzo (novel)', u'Production': u'Paramount Pictures', u'Actors': u'Marlon Brando, Al Pacino, James Caan, Richard S. Castellano', u'Type': u'movie', u'imdbVotes': u'1,235,597', u'Website': u'http://www.thegodfather.com', u'Director': u'Francis Ford Coppola', u'Released': u'24 Mar 1972', u'Awards': u'Won 3 Oscars. Another 23 wins & 27 nominations.', u'Genre': u'Crime, Drama', u'imdbRating': u'9.2', u'Language': u'English, Italian, Latin', u'Country': u'USA', u'BoxOffice': u'N/A', u'Runtime': u'175 min', u'imdbID': u'tt0068646', u'Metascore': u'100', u'Response': u'True', u'Year': u'1972'}
]'''

data = [ast.literal_eval(s) for s in x.split('\n') if s.startswith('{')]

with open('movie_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    fieldnames = list(data[0].keys())
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writeheader()  # optional
    for obj in data:
        writer.writerow(obj)
```

Contents of the `movie_data.csv` created:

Output:

```
"Plot","Rated","Title","Ratings","DVD","Writer","Production","Actors","Type","imdbVotes","Website","Director","Released","Awards","Genre","imdbRating","Language","Country","BoxOffice","Runtime","imdbID","Metascore","Response","Year"
"Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.","R","The Shawshank Redemption","[{'Source': 'Internet Movie Database', 'Value': '9.3/10'}, {'Source': 'Rotten Tomatoes', 'Value': '91%'}, {'Source': 'Metacritic', 'Value': '80/100'}]","N/A","Stephen King (short story ""Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption""), Frank Darabont (screenplay)","Columbia Pictures","Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman, Bob Gunton, William Sadler","movie","1,814,175","N/A","Frank Darabont","14 Oct 1994","Nominated for 7 Oscars. Another 19 wins & 30 nominations.","Crime, Drama","9.3","English","USA","N/A","142 min","tt0111161","80","True","1994"
"The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.","R","The Godfather","[{'Source': 'Internet Movie Database', 'Value': '9.2/10'}, {'Source': 'Rotten Tomatoes', 'Value': '99%'}, {'Source': 'Metacritic', 'Value': '100/100'}]","09 Oct 2001","Mario Puzo (screenplay), Francis Ford Coppola (screenplay), Mario Puzo (novel)","Paramount Pictures","Marlon Brando, Al Pacino, James Caan, Richard S. Castellano","movie","1,235,597","http://www.thegodfather.com","Francis Ford Coppola","24 Mar 1972","Won 3 Oscars. Another 23 wins & 27 nominations.","Crime, Drama","9.2","English, Italian, Latin","USA","N/A","175 min","tt0068646","100","True","1972"
```

Comment: thank you for that, but im new in python and i dont really understand that + the new errors appear. is there any simpler way to do what i need? thanks

Comment: Doro: Sorry, this is about as simple as I can make it. I suggest you take the time to understand what it's doing—as that would be very worthwhile in my opinion (and probably allow you to fix whatever the new problems are). If afterwards you can't, then feel free to post a new question describing them.